# How can I tell biblatex to filter entries based on URL and URLDATE?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to create two separate lists of references using `biblatex`.  The first one should contain literature references, the second one online references.  My criterion is that any entry with both a `Url` and a `Urldate` in the BibTeX file should be an online source.  So I defined a “bibcheck” like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\defbibcheck{online}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ 
    not test {\iffieldundef{Url}} and not test {\iffieldundef{Urldate}}
  }{% Entry has both url and urldate -> it's a web source  
  }{%
    \skipentry
  }
}

\defbibcheck{hasurl}{%
  \iffieldundef{Url}{\skipentry}{}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {http://www.google.com/},
  urldate = {2012-06-21}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {http://www.google.com/}
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Charlie},
  urldate = {2012-06-21}
}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Delta}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[check=online]
\printbibliography[check=hasurl]

\end{document}
```

This does not work, however, because it seems that in the bibcheck “routine” neither `Url` nor `Urldate` are set – even though they are printed correctly in the list of references.
I tried outputting the value of the `Url` field using `\thefield{url}` and it only returns an empty string.

How can I filter based on `Url` and `Urldate`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your example is that "URLDATE" is not a field. If you check the manual, all the "*DATE" fields are split into their components by the backend and so if you change "urldate" to to "urlyear" then it works.

An alternative is to use the sourcemapping feature with biber:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url]
      \step[fieldsource=urldate]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={online}]
    }
  }
}
```

This will give everything with both URL and URLDATE the keyword "online" which you can then use for bib filtering. Since URLDATE is part of the backend datamodel, you can use it there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  This works infact for the `urldate` field.  But I still do not know how to test against the `url` field.

Comment: I think you're getting confused by the fact that your example has the field names in mixed case. "Url" won't work but "url" will. The URL field can be tested against but URLDATE can't as it doesn't exist as a .bbl field.

Comment: @PLK: `urldate` is defined via `DeclareFieldFormat` in `biblatex.def`

Comment: Yes, as a format but not as a field. If you look in the .bbl for this example, you'll see that there is no urldate. It's been split into urlyear, urlmonth and urlday. See the section 4.2.4.3 of the manual.

Comment: @PLK: thats correct, but the problem is that biblatex uses only the fields defined in the bbl and not the ones defined by itself.

Comment: True, but technically, the *DATE fields are part of the biblatex+backend data model-so they are available to the backend (see edited answer). The backend consumes them and gives more fine-grained information.

Comment: @PLK: You say `url` can be tested against – but how?  Testing `\iffieldundef{urlyear}` works for me (as a substitute for `urldate`), but `iffieldundef{url}` doesn't.

Comment: That is strange, I tested it and it works for me as long as it's lower case.

Comment: I double-checked my solution and I can't reproduce the error.  Maybe I didn't clean all temporary files during testing the last time.  Seems to work fine now...  Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 5):

The test on the field `urldate`, because `biblatex` uses only the fields defined in the `.bbl`file. However, why don't you define such entries not as an `online` type? Then you can test for `\ifentrytype` (I used `biber` in my example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\defbibcheck{online}{\ifentrytype{online}{}{\skipentry}}
\defbibcheck{hasurl}{\iffieldundef{url}{\skipentry}{}}
\defbibcheck{hasurldate}{\iffieldundef{urlyear}{\skipentry}{}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  urldate = {2012-06-21},
  url = {http://www.google.com/},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {http://www.google.com/}
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Charlie},
  urldate = {2012-06-21},
}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Delta},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography[check=online]
\printbibliography[check=hasurl]
\printbibliography[check=hasurldate]
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to format some online sources as, e.g., technical reports setting the type to `@techreport` while still including a URL and a URL date.  Also, my bibtex-file is rather comprehensive and it would be tedious to manually check all entries whether they should be `@online`.

Comment: @ilpssun: ok, the "field" `urldate` is internally divided into the separate fields `urlday`, `urlmonth`, and `urlyear`. If you run the test with `urlyear` instead of `urldate` then it should work. The problem is that `biblatex` defines the field urldate but uses for the check only the fields which are definied by biber